# hiding a row on the jsp in Struts 1.1

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Given the following,

```
<logic:notEqual name="ABCForm" property="externalFactor" value="true">
    <tr>
    <td width="20%" class="label"  height="14"><bean:message key="factorDefault"/></td>
    <td class="label">
        <html:radio property="defaultState" value="Y"><bean:message key="Yes"/></html:radio>
        <html:radio property="defaultState" value="N"><bean:message key="No"/></html:radio>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </logic:notEqual>
```

How do I hide this row on the page at all times without deleting data associated with this row in the database?

I tried replacing `logic:notEqual` with `logic:empty` and the jsp is blank for that div. I have tried simply removing this entire block of code, and of course that works. I am just concerned if that affects the database, or if there any pages that rely on data associated with the code snippet.

Comment: Whether or not it affects the DB depends on your back-end code.

Answer (score 0):

Mr.gabybaby you do one thing...

in your database table you add another column like `status` 
by default `status` value is `active` if any user wants to delete any record through your JSP just you change that record `status`=`inactive`..

you should display only `active` records in jsp...

i think this is the solution for your requirement